# Working with factors: put two function into dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr, factors

I was just looking for a tidier way to get the output of the following data:

```
library(dplyr)
library(gapminder)

gapminder$continent %>% class() 
gapminder$continent %>% nlevels()
gapminder$continent %>% levels()
gapminder$continent %>% str()
```

It looks a bit repetitive, so I want to merge it into one line using dplyr, so I tried the following:

```
gapminder$continent %>% class() %>% nlevels() %>% levels() %>% str()
#AND
gapminder %>% summarise_at(vars(continent), list(class = class, nlevels = nlevels,levels= levels))
```

but of course, those does not work. I am not sure how can I get the output.

The similar issue arises when I want to plot changing factors:

```
gapminder$continent = gapminder$continent %>%
  fct_relevel( "Oceania", "Europe")

gapminder %>%
  ggplot() +
  geom_bar(aes(fct_relevel( continent,"Africa", "Oceania"))) +
  coord_flip()+
  theme_bw() +
  labs(color = "country")
```

Can I combine them together?

Comment: Not clear what you are after.  Do you need `gapminder %>% summarise(class = class(continent), nlev = nlevels(continent))` or `gapminder %>% summarise_at(vars(continent), list(class = class, nlevels = nlevels))`

Comment: I don't see a difference in the output files. I just what to explore the structure of factors using following commands: ```class(gapminder$continent)
levels(gapminder$continent)
nlevels(gapminder$continent)
str(gapminder$continent)```

Comment: What's the output you're trying to get exactly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If we want to apply a set of functions, wrap it in a `list`

```
library(gapminder)
library(purrr)
library(dplyr)
map(list(class, nlevels, levels, str), ~ 
       gapminder %>%
         pull(continent) %>% 
         .x())
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, Can you please explain teh following operations: why do we put `~ ` and what does `.x()` do?

Comment: @user3617715  The `~` tilda is a way to pass anonymous function in tidyverse.  If you don't do it you can use `function(x) x` where `x` replaces the `.x`